# How to access variable in angularjs1 after broken down html in to several child html files?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have broken down my main html page to several sub pages and imported the child pages to
main html file. Now, It seems each page refers to different '$scope' variables. I need to refer ng-modle="My-model" from one child page to another child page. Is that possble to do? My sample code as follows,

search-parent.html

```
<div class="widgets">
  <div class="row accordions-row">
    <div class="col-md-6" include-with-scope="serch.html"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" include-with-scope="other-search.html"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

search.html

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mymodel">
</div>
```

other-search.html

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mymodel">
</div>
```

Angular module configuration

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('my-module', [])
    .config(routeConfig);

    /** @ngInject */
    function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
            url: '/search',
            controller: 'ctrl',
            templateUrl: 'search-parent.html',
        });
    }
})();
```

thank you!

Comment: You also need to specify the controller attached to these pages (`ng-controller="myController"`), so the variables belong to the same scope, or something like that

Comment: Use a service to share data across various parts of the app

Comment: @JeremyThille OP is declaring controller in routing config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared services or broadcasting events or $rootScope or you can maintain the same controller for all child templates. But using $rootScope is not good approach.

[Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: $broadcast and use listeners to gain control over requests. To me $rootscope feels very brute Force (but I too have used it in cases).